# Finding the scalar parametric equation of the line

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am trying to find the scalar parametric equation of the line which passes through the point $ A =[1,2,1]$ and is perpendicular to the plane $2z-y+2x=2$. But I am not sure how to go about doing this?

Firstly I am trying to get three answers in terms of $x=... y=...$ and $ z=...$

So I assume the normal vector is: $n=<2,-1,2>$

Then this becomes $2(x-1)-(y-2)+2(z-1)=0$

But then I am not sure what the question is really asking? Like what does $x$ equal? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the normal to the plane $(2, -1, 2)$. This is the direction vector of your line.
The line passes through $(1,2,1)$ so the line equation is
$$
(x,y,z)=(1,2,1)+\lambda(2, -1, 2)
$$
where $\lambda$ is the parameter. Then you have 3 individual equations, one each for $x,y$ and $z$ in terms of your parameter.

For example, $x=1+2\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no scalar equation of a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but there is a set of parametric equations
$$\left\{
\begin{align}
x&=1+2t\\
y&=2-t\\
z&=1+2t
\end{align}\right.$$

Comment: How did you get these? I can see that it is just the point plus the equation component but what happens to the $2$ in the  plane equation?

Comment: The constant in the planar equation determines the plane's position in space and does not have anything to do with its direction vectors or normal vector, just like how the $y$-intercept of a linear function has nothing to do with its slope, etc.